# How to make a footer resposive bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys got a simple question about bootstrap, trying to make a footer resposive but for some reason i cant seem to do it, any help on making this footer resposive for mobiles etc would be great.

So far i have:

Not sure what i should be doing, new to this :0

Thanks for the help

Comment: You may want to read the Bootstrap docs and try few things.

Comment: @SandeepNayak i tried teh col-sm etc but just does not seem to work , so hoping someone can show me

Comment: Agreed with @SandeepNayak ^^. Your are missing the basic classes of bootstrap such as rows & columns. Also make sure your bootstrap file is being pulled in correctly.

Comment: `container` should be your wrapper and then comes `footer` with bootstrap grid classes `col-**-**`. All your footer content should be inside `row`

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Yes u have to understand i have tried this, but like i said i went back to the orgianl version because i cant get it to work, that is why i am waiting for someone hopefully to show me , how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what kind of look your going for but if you are looking for but assuming that you are going for something that has a left and right section and then at mobile sizes stacks to make it more viewable you can do something like the following:

Here is a fiddle to show you the result [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6c39n69x/)

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 footer-left">
        <img class="footer-logo" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 footer-right">
        <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fa fa-instagram" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

And responsive Css

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .footer-right{text-align:right;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .footer-left, .footer-right{text-align:center;}
  .footer-logo{display:block;margin:5px auto;}
}
```

Comment: Perfect ta x helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example of how you can structure your HTML:

```css
footer{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <footer class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="col-sm-6 pull-left">Left content</p>
        <p class="col-sm-6 pull-right">Right content</p>
      </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Learn about Bootstrap Grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Simple Bootstrap Layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle of your missing elements: https://jsfiddle.net/odx59t0p/

```
            <div class="logo1">
                <img src="Image/Logo.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <p><a href="#" onClick="swap('refabout')">Reference/About</a>          
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please note: The only things that have been added are:

1. Links to required CSS / JS files (which you should already have in your head tags)
2. "row" class to "navbar-text"
3. "col-sm-*" classes to divs around menu items.